# Why can a typedef-name for a struct not be used interchangeably with the struct name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8c456320ee02aab)) does not compile:

```
struct S {};
typedef struct S T;
S s = T();          // OK
struct T * p;       // error: elaborated type refers to a typedef
T::T(){}            // error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

Why is the language designed to not permit the last two lines?

---

Relevant Standard quote (N4140 §7.1.3/8):

> [ Note: A *typedef-name* that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a *class-name* (9.1).
>   If a *typedef-name* is used to identify the subject of an *elaborated-type-specifier* (7.1.6.3), a class definition (Clause 9), a constructor declaration (12.1), or a destructor declaration (12.4), the program is ill-formed.
>   —end note ]

Comment: What is your question -- are you asking why the language is what it is? The note is presumably just highlighting some consequences of the language rules that are not immediately obvious.

Comment: It looks like you have three different questions there?

Comment: @BenVoigt They are all related to 7.1.3/8

Comment: `T{};` does not compile because it is not a declaration, and only declarations may occur at namespace scope. (That would be fine if it were at block scope).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think you have just answered the part related to the "class definition" in the Note, and I have no problem with accepting this. It seems reasonable enough to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Belloc: But they do not all have the same answer, ergo three different questions.

Comment: @Belloc I have cleaned up your question as it seems to be asking - feel free to roll back if it is inappropriate.  The `T{}` thing seems unrelated to the main question since it is actually equivalent to `S{}` (and neither are allowed in this context)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Much better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So there are three unrelated issues. The first one you have in the quote you provide:

```
struct T * p;
```

That is illegal as `T` is a typedef.

```
T{};
```

That is illegal at namespace level, but would be legal in other concepts, for example as part of the initialization of a global, or inside a function:

```
T t = T{};
void f() { T{}; }
```

It really means to create a *value-initialized* temporary object of type `T`.

```
T::T(){}
```

That would be a valid definition for a default constructor, except that you did not declare one. If you modify the `S` to have a user declared default constructor that would work:

```
struct S { S(); };
```

**Why is the language designed to not permit the last two lines?**

Those two lines, in the updated question are:

```
struct T* p;
T::T() {}
```

The second one is legal, but you are trying to define a function that has not been declared as a member, so this is also unrelated to the original text.  Which leaves us with one: `struct T* p`.

The motive comes from C.  The identifiers for user defined types and other names appear to live in different scopes, when lookup is trying to resolve a name not qualified with `struct` or `enum`, it will ignore struct and enums, when trying to resolve a `struct` or `enum` it ignores everything else. The following is valid C (and C++):

```
struct T {};          // 1
typedef struct S {} T;  // 2
struct T t;
```

In C++ the rules for lookup changed a bit and you can use the type specifiers without explicitly qualifying it but that is a different thing.  Additionally, typedef-ed names can be used in other contexts that were not possible in C.

An special case is lookup for an elaborated type specifier, should the typedef-ed name be usable in an elaborated type specifier? If it was, the semantics of the program above would change and where in C `t` is of type `T` (defined in 1), in C++ it would become `S` (defined in 2).

Note that this is to some extent a wild guess, I did not make the rules and I don't know what went into consideration there. Note that C and C++ were never really compatible in this respect, a similar example changes semantics in C and C++:

```
int T;
void f() {
   struct T { int data[10]; };
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(T));
}
```

That program will print a number 10x larger in C++ than in C.  But the ability to use a type without having to qualify it with `class` or `struct` was probably more important than breaking compatibility in a few cases...

Comment: I see now that the last 2 cases do not stand as reasonable questions. But why doesn't the language allow `struct T* p;` ?

Comment: @Belloc: I was in the process of writing that up... C compatibility

Comment: But `struct T t;` doesn't compile in C++, and the error message is the same as the one for `struct T* p;`

Comment: But you wrote above that the code was valid in C and C++. So, I still don't have a clear understanding about the issue with C compatibility, you mentioned above.

Comment: `struct T {};  typedef struct S {} T; `, still doesn't compile in C++.

Comment: `That would be a valid definition for a default constructor, except that you did not declare one. If you modify the S to have a user declared default constructor that would work: struct S { S(); };`. But the following snippet doesn't compile either: `struct S { S(); ~S(); }; typedef struct S T; T::T(){}
T::~T(){}`. But again, this is OK according to the Note. My question then makes some sense. Why it doesn't compile? Why was the Note written this way?